# Error when working with AspectJ and Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, aspectj

I am trying to work with Scala and AspectJ on IntelliJ as the IDE. #The file structure

[image]

Sample.scala - (The class which consists of the main method)

```
package sample

class SampleClass {
  def printSample():Unit = println("hello")
}

object SampleObject extends App {
  val sample = new SampleClass
  sample.printSample()
}
```

Tracer.scala - (The Tracer function or in other words the aspect)

```
package sample

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation._

@Aspect
class Tracer {

  @Before("execution(* sample.SampleClass.printSample(..))")
  def printSample() {
    println("Printing sample:")
  }
}
```

build.sbt - in order to run the sbt command(sbt compile and sbt run)

```
name := "testingAspectScalaFullexample"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.5"
lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.lightbend.sbt.aspectj",
  version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
)


lazy val sample = (project in file("."))
  .settings(buildSettings)
  .aggregate(tracer, instrumented)

// precompiled aspects
lazy val tracer = (project in file("tracer"))
  .enablePlugins(SbtAspectj)
  .settings(buildSettings)
  .settings(
    // input compiled scala classes
    aspectjInputs in Aspectj += (aspectjCompiledClasses in Aspectj).value,

    // ignore warnings
    aspectjLintProperties in Aspectj += "invalidAbsoluteTypeName = ignore",
    aspectjLintProperties in Aspectj += "adviceDidNotMatch = ignore",

    // replace regular products with compiled aspects
    products in Compile := (products in Aspectj).value
  )

// test that the instrumentation works
lazy val instrumented = (project in file("instrumented"))
  .enablePlugins(SbtAspectj)
  .settings(buildSettings)
  .settings(
    // add the compiled aspects from tracer
    aspectjBinaries in Aspectj ++= (products in Compile in tracer).value,

    // weave this project's classes
    aspectjInputs in Aspectj += (aspectjCompiledClasses in Aspectj).value,
    products in Compile := (products in Aspectj).value,
    products in Runtime := (products in Compile).value
  ).dependsOn(tracer)

// for sbt scripted test:
TaskKey[Unit]("check") := {
  import scala.sys.process.Process

  val cp = (fullClasspath in Compile in instrumented).value
  val mc = (mainClass in Compile in instrumented).value
  val opts = (javaOptions in run in Compile in instrumented).value

  val expected = "Printing sample:\nhello\n"
  val output = Process("java", opts ++ Seq("-classpath", cp.files.absString, mc getOrElse "")).!!
  if (output != expected) {
    println("Unexpected output:")
    println(output)
    println("Expected:")
    println(expected)
    sys.error("Unexpected output")
  } else {
    print(output)
  }
}
```

However when I run sbt compile, this error crops up:

```
Weaving 1 input to ,<path>\SpringIn28Minutes-master\SpringIn28Minutes-master\testingAspectScalaFullexample\tracer\target\scala-2.12\aspectj\classes...
[error] error can't determine superclass of missing type java.lang.Object
[error] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=0 AopXmls=#0
[error]  [Xlint:cantFindType]
[error] org.aspectj.bridge.AbortException: AspectJ failed
[error]         at com.lightbend.sbt.SbtAspectj$Ajc$.runAjcMain(SbtAspectj.scala:212)
[error]         at com.lightbend.sbt.SbtAspectj$Ajc$.runAjc(SbtAspectj.scala:124)
[error]         at com.lightbend.sbt.SbtAspectj$Ajc$.$anonfun$ajcTask$2(SbtAspectj.scala:111)
[error]         at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$1(FileFunction.scala:80)
[error]         at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$4(FileFunction.scala:153)
[error]         at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:414)
[error]         at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:394)
[error]         at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$3(FileFunction.scala:149)
[error]         at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:414)
[error]         at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:389)
[error]         at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$2(FileFunction.scala:148)
[error]         at com.lightbend.sbt.SbtAspectj$Ajc$.$anonfun$ajcTask$1(SbtAspectj.scala:116)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executo
rs.java:515)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoo
lExecutor.java:1130)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPo
olExecutor.java:630)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
[error] (tracer / Aspectj / ajc) org.aspectj.bridge.AbortException: AspectJ failed
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question does not contain any code. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, then edit your question in order to become one. Ideally, share your sample project on GitHub. Like this, nobody can help you, the question will only attract close votes. P.S.: If you are the guy who approached me privately on Telegram, I told you about the MCVE requirement already. You are a master degree student in some computer science related subject, you should know how to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: If you edit a question, you need to notify people that you did it. SO has not automatic notification for edits of other people's questions or answer, only if there are new answers or comments. I just noticed by chance because the browser tab was still open.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am not a Scala user. But to me it looks as if you define a regular class `Sample` and then a singleton object with exactly the same name. Does that make any sense, or did you post pseudo code?

Comment: I have updated the source code. ScalaObject is creating a new instance of the class SampleClass, and then executing the function printSample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you are using [this example](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/tree/master/src/sbt-test/compile/annotations) from the plugin source code repository. Why didn't you just say so and link to it? You made it look as if you created the sample by yourself. I found it and also the `project/plugins.sbt` which you did *not* post here. Like I told you before in our chat, I am a Scala noob, I never used it in my whole life and had no idea that a file was missing. That cost me a lot of time. Why did you post an incomplete sample project here instead of publishing it on GitHub like I asked you to? Then I could just have cloned the project and run it. Not until I found the sample code online, did I realise that yours was incomplete.

Furthermore, my IDE IntelliJ IDEA cannot import the sample project, there must be some kind of bug in the current version. I can only compile and run from sbt shell. There, I could finally reproduce your problem.

Actually, the explanation is quite simple: The plugin is outdated and ought to be updated ASAP. It depends on AspectJ Compiler Tools 1.8.10 which only supports Java 8. It is not even the most recent 1.8 release, that should be 1.8.13. Also, the plugin exports AspectJ Runtime 1.8.10 as a runtime dependency to projects using the plugin. See also:

- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/blob/8ff3a1ad4224934dabe222205eb89c985670f240/build.sbt#L7
- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/blob/8ff3a1ad4224934dabe222205eb89c985670f240/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/sbt/SbtAspectj.scala#L30

As long as you compile and run your project on JDK 1.8, everything is fine. If you use a more recent JDK, the solution is to override the dependencies. Put this into `project/plugins.sbt`:

```scala
addSbtPlugin("org.jetbrains" % "sbt-ide-settings" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.11.0")
dependencyOverrides += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjrt" % "1.9.6"
dependencyOverrides += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjtools" % "1.9.6"
```

AspectJ 1.9.6 supports up to language level 14. Version 1.9.7 supporting Java 15+16 will be released soon. But if you run on JDK 16, but compile to no higher than target 14, you should be fine.

---

BTW, the test is platform-specific and will fail on Windows because there it expects UNIX line separators (LF), while Windows uses CR+LF:

```scala
val expected = "Printing sample:\nhello\n"
```

You should change that to:

```scala
val LF = System.lineSeparator()
val expected = "Printing sample:" + LF + "hello" + LF
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helped. After arranging some minor things, the project worked. Thanks a lot :)