# AspectJ with Akka systems

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka, aspectj

Just for reference, this question continues with question named : [Error when working with AspectJ and Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67402027/error-when-working-with-aspectj-and-scala)

I am trying to use AspectJ with Scala, specifically working with Akka actor systems.

I have been producing a pointcut of this type :

```
@Around("\"execution (* akka.actor.ActorRef.!(..)) \" + \"&& args(message, sender)\", argNames = \"(message, sender)\")")
  def printSample() {
    println("receive message ")
  }
```

However an error crops up saying :

```
Invalid pointcut '"execution (* akka.actor.ActorRef.!(..)) " + "&& args(message, sender)", argNames = "(message, sender)")': org.aspectj.weaver.
patterns.ParserException: identifier at position 0
[error] org.aspectj.bridge.AbortException: AspectJ failed
```

Comment: To be honest FP in general and Scala in particular does not need Aspect Oriented Programming. Higher order functions will provide you with the same functionality without making it hard to debug and understand. For example `@Around` can be replaced with By Name Parameter (https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) or passing a function into around function. Moreover Akka itself has many event hooks which you can utilize. AOP should be dead by now. It served its purpose for cumbersome OOP languages, now every modern language has better abstractions like HOF or decorators in Python

Comment: It's also worth nothing that `!` being called in no way implies that a message has been received, only that it's been sent.  Believing that a message send implies a message being received is quite likely to lead to pain down the road.

Comment: Feedback, please. You keep asking new questions, then deleting some of them again along with the comments other people have spent time writing. Let's close older ones first, shall we?

Answer (score 1):

Your pointcut is probably a copy & paste error, you quoted it:

```java
@Around("\"execution (* akka.actor.ActorRef.!(..)) \" + \"&& args(message, sender)\", argNames = \"(message, sender)\")")
```

If you fix that to read

```java
@Around(
  "execution (* akka.actor.ActorRef.!(..)) && args(message, sender)",
  argNames = "(message, sender)"
)
```

then you have the two annotation parameters you probably intended to use. But the `ActorRef.!(..)` with the `!` still looks strange, you probably mean `*`. If the argument names in the advice method are identical to the ones used in `args()`, you can also omit that part completely and avoid boilerplate:

```java
@Around("execution(* akka.actor.ActorRef.*(..)) && args(message, sender)")
```

That should do it.

Bottom line: Your problem is about basic Java annotations and AspectJ usage, not about Scala or Akka or whatever you thought was the problem.